# D3 getting data from multiple column CSV

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm following this example for a [multi-line graph](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/d8be922a10cb0b148cd5)

I want to plot each forecast in my CSV using values for years 2010, 2011, 2012.

**forecast.csv**

```
forecast,2010,2011,2012
Outlook,87,88,88
Reform,50,20,88
Renewal,43,21,88
```

If my data was simple like the example link, the code to build the chart would look like this:

```
var priceline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.forecast;})
    .entries(data);

dataNest.forEach(function(d) {

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", priceline(d.values)); 

             console.log(dataNest)
});
```

However my data is coming from a multi column CSV.

I'm trying to nest the forecasts, so each forecast would have an array of year and value pairs. i.e

```
[0] Object
      [key] Outlook
      [values]
         [0] year: 2010
             value: 28
         [1] year: 2011
             value: 88
```

but dataNest currently looks like this

```
  [0] Object
      [key] Outlook
      [values]
         [0] 2010: 87
             2011: 88
             2012: 88
```

There are many other years in the real data so transposing is not an option. How can I draw a line from this multi column CSV data?

Comment: Have you thought about melting the data first, so that you have year on the second column and the corresponding values on the third?

Comment: Yes I have, but my data is too large - there are 30+ years for each forecast. Can I do this with d3 or do I need to learn to do this in R for example?

Comment: If the data is static, you can simply hardcode the year value once, iterate through the CSV file using `d3.csv()` and then push each year into an array of objects?

Comment: I think thats what I need to do - how can I push each year into an array of objects? I've been using d3.queue if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your data format or modify your `d3.nest` function. However, I reckon the easiest solution is using plain JavaScript to modify your array:

```
dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
    d.values.forEach(function(e) {
        var myArr = [];
        for (var key in e) {
            if (e[key] != d.key) {
                myArr.push({
                    "year": key,
                    "value": e[key]
                });
            }
        }
        d.values = myArr;
    })
})
```

Here is a demo, using the data in your question:

```js
var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text());

var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.forecast;
    })
    .entries(data);

dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
    d.values.forEach(function(e) {
        var myArr = [];
        for (var key in e) {
            if (e[key] != d.key) {
                myArr.push({
                    "year": key,
                    "value": e[key]
                });
            }
        }
        d.values = myArr;
    })
})

console.log(dataNest)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">forecast,2010,2011,2012
Outlook,87,88,88
Reform,50,20,88
Renewal,43,21,88</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How should I find the x and y domain for the nested values? eg: x.domain(d3.extent(dataNest, function(d) { return d.year; }));